# Create header from Dynamic Library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, lazarus

I just bought a shared library (.so shared object) which represents a device SDK.
The seller didn't send me the header .h files for C/C++ development. They sent me Pascal and Java examples using interface (java class) and Pascal global functions referring to stdcalls also referring this external .so file.

They sent me examples and demo on how to use the .so shared object on Pascal and Java.
They also sent me an document detailing all function calls (parameters type, etc...) in .so file. which I nm the .so file and saw the exactly function symbols on it.

My question is, how to create a C++ header, which I can use it as a class object in C++.

I did a very dirty usage of this .so using dlopen, dlsym and dlclose directly on my software, but I felt it very dirty. So, I would like to create a class like the java interface for this so I can make a cleaner code and also run in separately on a Thread without freezing my GUI like is occurring right now.

The Pascal (Lazarus) function definitions they provide me:

```
  THREAD_READ1  = class(TThread)
    fEvent:PRTLEvent;
    procedure Execute; override;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

{ Functions headers }
function SDK_Initialize: integer; stdcall; external 'sdk.so';
function SDK_Finalize: integer; stdcall; external 'sdk.so';
function SDK_DigitalREAD(pTemplate: Pointer): integer; stdcall; external 'sdk.so';
function SDK_READBMP(var iRetorno, iSize: Integer): Pointer; stdcall; external 'sdk.so';
function SDK_READ(pTemplate: Pointer; var sTemplate: integer; pImage: Pointer; var sImage:integer; intWHITE: integer; intIMG: integer): integer; stdcall; external 'sdk.so';
function SDK_Cancel: integer; stdcall; external 'sdk.so';
function SDK_Compare(pSample1, pSample2: Pointer): integer; stdcall; external 'sdk.so';

function SDK_Version: PAnsiChar; stdcall; external 'sdk.so';
function SDK_Return(intReturn: integer): PAnsiChar; stdcall; external 'sdk.so';
```

I need to know how to port and wrap these function calls into a C++ class and run some functions into a different Thread, for example:

```
    Class Device : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
private:
QThread thread1;
QThread *thread2;
...
public:
SDK functions here
...
};
```

I don't know how to construct the functions header in the code above. And I don't know also to make it thread safe as following:
I must call SDK_READ on a Thread to put the device into read state and not get my GUI frozen waiting the device response.
I also must call SDK_Cancel to cancel reading state and finish the thread running any SDK_READ functions

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to generate one automatically. A lot of the header information is erased (via inlining or constant folding) or irreversibly munged during compilation. The correct approach would be to ask the company where the C/C++ header is.

Comment: The header is actually you least problem. Worse are most likely the calling conventions differ between the languages. Get your money back; a library which does not provide a C or C++ header but one for Pascal can't be worth the money.

Comment: If you know Pascal, you can look at the Pascal function definitions and ascertain what the equivalent would be for your C++ compiler.  From what I remember, Pascal definitions to external functions are pretty straightforward.  Personally I wouldn't even look at the Java definitions -- Pascal is the closest you'll get in getting the right parameter types, return calls, and calling convention.

Comment: Do you know which variety of Pascal?  Some of them use name mangling or have extra features that may be a hassle to work with from C or C++ (like data types with additional information hidden in them and no direct C or C++ equivalent)...

Comment: PaulMcKenzie and @Dmitri,
The Pascal example they provide me are from Lazarus and they define the functions as you can see as following answer:

Comment: If you can get hold of Delphi, try to compile it with Delphi. Delphi can be made to generate header files for a unit (if you can make it compile -- Delphi is not 100% compatible with FreePascal). I'm not sure if FreePascal can do the same.

Comment: Are these all the definitions you need? A few functions and one class? That should be easy to do manually. But what on earth makes the providers think you can use a class based on TThread in any other language but FreePascal? That is terribly bad programming. If they provide a shared library, they should *at least* provide C bindings.

Comment: You won't be able to use that code in any other C++ compiler except perhaps C++Builder. But then you'd have to get a .dll and not an .so. These providers didn't provide you with enough material. This is only usable from FreePascal.

Comment: I don't need the Thread class, I just need the functions (some of them), but wrapped into some class that I can execute in a different Thread.

Comment: Then you will have to define the header file manually. Not too much work, if those are the only functions.

Comment: @Olaf: the calling convention is stdcall, so I assume that this is only for Windows (although then I wonder why it is not a DLL). But I agree that they should provide a C header for this.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis See the timestamps! OP took quite some time to add this relevant information. The question is still too broad.

Comment: @Olaf: In many places, people celebrate Easter. That might explain the slow response. I don't think this is too broad, though. Just weird, because the example given by the vendor doesn't quite make sense. Stdcall is only for Windows, but Windows doesn't generally use .so's.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: OP apparently asks how to translate these headers. I mentioned the slow response just because I did not see understand why you pinged me with your comment, as you refer to information I could not have at the time of writing my comment. But even with that, the question is still beyond what this site is for. There are good reasons we expect **specific** questions with a specific problem statement. Such questions are not helpful for the community. (May I remind you we are not a personal problem solver site, how unsatisfying this might be for a single asker).

Comment: @Olaf: Ok, I misunderstood, sorry.

Comment: FWIW: As a reaction to this and similar problems, I wrote [DLL DOs and DONTs](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html).

Answer (score 0):

The SDK* functions are 1:1 mappable to GCC since Lazarus' compiler, Freepascal, is generally compatible to gcc on a linking level.  All types are primitive types, so it just needs basic syntax conversion and use of whatever stdcall calling convention macro is needed. VAR parameters add one extra * indirection.

Watch out with "integer", which is generally int32, but strictly speaking that depends on compiler mode. (objfpc and delphi=int32, default modes and TP =int16). That is the only good thing of the TThread class derivation though, it makes sure this is a Object Pascal mode.

The Thread_read1_ class however is native Object (OOP) Pascal, and is not interfacable from external code (even a significantly different FreePascal or Delphi version) and would need wrapping just like any C++ class for a plain C interface or different C++ compiler would. (e.g. compare with like when gcc changed mangling for C++ classes several times in the past).

In theory you could try to hack into it, but that is not advisable, specially since TThread also creates a lot of TLS context. This part of the header doesn't seem to be reusable from external languages or versions

Spending Eur 5000 to use Delphi as a header convertor to convert 10 functions like Rudy suggests might be a bit overkill though.

--- response after more details in private mail

The whole thing is very unclear, and the header does not give much information. In a private mail the poster explained the situation and it seems that the functions work fine straight, but not when used from threads.

It is possible that running FPC code in threads not initialized by the FPC
runtime leads to problems.

The URL that I posted in the comments earlier (
http://wiki.freepascal.org/Multithreaded_Application_Tutorial#External_threads
) describes some causes, created by people that embedded CEF(Chrome browser)
in Lazarus applications. CEF is internally threaded too, and calls pascal callbacks in its threads.

Basically there are two possible causes:

1. threading in FPC RTL hasn't been initialized (done by creating a dummy thread)
2. If the Pascal code uses FPC runtime components like dynamic memory
   management or standard file descriptors that use TLS variables, you must
   call a function to do so.  (the "ExternalThread" bit in the link).

It might be a piece of cake if the SDK make wrapped those pieces in the SDK
for you.  Getting access to the potentially not exported (or maybe partially
not even linked in) RTL symbols statically linked into the .so will be
extremely hard though, **so talking to the SDK vendor seems the only sane
avenue IMHO**, or abandon the thread aspirations and e.g. work with a worker
application that interfaces the SDK that is controlled using pipes.

The SDK api is a bit naive and doesn't sound if it has been iterated, and doesn't prepare for the case where the might be multiple language runtimes in one application.

Comment: Delphi does not have to cost 5000 Euro. There are or have been free versions. The Starter version is also very cheap. And well, he could ask someone with Delphi to try it. He only needs the resulting header, right?

Comment: And well, it should be int32, I guess. There is no stdcall in 16 bit mode.

Comment: All in all, the people who provided the .so did not think very far. Writing a shared object (or DLL) that can only be used from one single language is pretty shortsighted, IMO.

Comment: @Marco van de Voort I actually don't need the TThread class. However, I would like to know how to execute all this functions on a different thread from my application.

I have created a functional code using dlopen, dlsym as I said. However, If I put this class on a Thread I get Segmentation Fault after a mutex_trylock on disassembler.

Comment: @Marco van de Voort, using Delphi is not an option! I prefer to hack into this and make it work.

I think it is possible to make it work as I made it through dlsym, dlopen...But I don't know how to create these function definitions into a class and put this to run on a thread.

Comment: @Marco I think that what I really need is not clear. And what I really need is:
I need to know how to port these functions into C++ class that I can run separately in a thread.
For example

Class Device : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
private:
QThread *thread1;
QThread *thread2;
...
public:
SDK* functions here
...
};

and to run some SDK*functions in a thread:
For example:
SDK_READ in a thread to put the device into a read state
and SDK_Cancel to get the device out from the read state and finish the thread running SDK_READ

Comment: The header does not provide any information about threading, you must consult the docs then. If it is something TLS related, see http://wiki.freepascal.org/Multithreaded_Application_Tutorial#External_threads

Comment: Just as how it doesn't specify if you have to free the pansichar (char *) function result or not.

Comment: If the functions use threading internally, it might not be easy to convert this. If you can't use Delphi (I only mentioned that as a way to obtain a C header from the Pascal source, not to use it for programming), use FreePascal itself. That should work.

Comment: You should be able to create a simple "C" style header (extern "C") for this. I would do a library listing to see the actual names that are assigned to the functions. It looks like they have written this so that it can be called from C++/C relatively easy.

Comment: Thank you @user3344003, it worked nicely with extern "C". it worked... However, I am experiencing segmentation fault when I execute it in a thread.

Comment: The library may not be thread-safe. You might have to put guards around the calls. Or only call the library from one thread.